# Two issues: Causing Sumatra not to jump to document beginning after compiling an writing under caption title

Tags: captions

I'm having two problems with my MiKTeX, TeXnicCenter and SumatraPDF configuration

1. The first issue is about `sumatra`. I like the fact that `sumatra` does not need to be closed upon re-compilation of my document. However what I don't like is that everytime I recompile `sumatra`, it jumps to the beginning of my documents instead of staying on the page it displayed before...
   What do I have to do to stay on the page that I viewed even after re-compilation?

**Edit: Solved! I have to use recompile instead of recompile and show :)**

**2. A typical caption below a picture looks like:**

> Fig 1.1: Whatever the content might be
>   ***_*__*_*__** it is described here.

My problem is that I'd like to write below "Fig 1.1" at the position of ***_*__*_*__**. I've managed to replace "Figure" by Fig, thus the lost space isn't that huge, but it's still annoying...

Can anybody help me with this?  Apart from these, I'm happy with my setup.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: You ask two question in one. It would be better to make two different questions. We like here to have one question - and answers to this question.  For your first question: tell us the versions of the programs you use, MiKTeX 2.9, ... For your second question would be a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) helpful ... BTW: the hanging figure paragraph helps finding special figures, I wouldn't change it ...

Comment: Thanks for the instructions! I use MikTex 2.9 alongside with Texniccenter 2 beta under windows 8 x64. Viewer is sumatra pdf, also in the newest version.

Comment: I don't know how to provide a minimum example since this would requite uploading an image or using a link... However I can tell you what I did: 1. created a document of type: \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrreprt} 2. included packages. Of interest might be: justification=RaggedLeft,
singlelinecheck=false,
figurename=Fig.,
aboveskip=7pt,
belowskip=0pt]{caption}. This changes Figure to Fig. Then I include images via: 
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{... .jpg}
\caption{My caption} 
\end{figure} The caption then looks like shown in my initial post. I'm unable to write below "Fig".

Comment: You can edit the minimum example into your post (that way you can indent it and make it look nicer) rather than putting it in the comment.

Also, as a workaround to your positioning issue, consider setting up forward search for SumatraPDF so that when you press 'Preview' it jumps to (approximately) the position the code you are viewing corresponds to.

Comment: Forward Search is working... When I double click in summatra it jumps to the appropriate passage in texnicCenter... My proplem however is the following: I'm viewing my pdf-document, lets say at page 8. Now I change something in this page and recompile. Sumatra then jumps to the first page after recompiling instead on staying on page 8, which I would prefer...

Comment: Okay, fixed the first issue: I have to click on recompile instea of recompile and view. This way sumatra stays on the page it was before. This leaves the caption-problem

Answer (score 2):

You gave no MWE so let's try it with the following one to solve your second problem:

```
\documentclass[%
  fontsize=12pt
 ,paper=a4
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[%
  justification=RaggedLeft  % caption right justified
% format=plain % hang for hanging paragraph <===========
 ,singlelinecheck=false
 ,figurename=Fig.
 ,aboveskip=7pt
 ,belowskip=0pt
]{caption}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure} 
  \centering 
  \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
  \caption{My caption My caption My caption My caption My caption 
    My caption My caption My caption My caption My caption My caption 
    My caption My caption My caption My caption My caption } 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This gives you as result: 
[image]

If you move the comment sign `%` from line 11 to 10 you get what you want (the option format is your friend):
[image]